# Laravel carbon время доставки

Tags: mysql, laravel, carbon

Через laravel migration я сделал таблицу с разными магазинами, у каждого магазина есть поле `delivery_time`. Я поставил тип time.

Тут я планировал указывать скорость доставки в часах - 0 часов, 12 часов, 36 часов и тд.

Как через seeder сюда добавить значение?

```js
Shop::factory()->create([
  'name' => 'Aliexpress',
  'description' => 'Chinese store',
  'warranty' => false,
  'delivery_time' => 36*60*60*1000 // In hours
]);

// or

Shop::factory()->create([
  'name' => 'Aliexpress',
  'description' => 'Chinese store',
  'warranty' => false,
  'delivery_time' => Carbon::createFromTimestamp(36*60*60*1000) // In hours
]);
```

Я пробовал так, но это не работает(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то `factory()` служит для заполнения фейковыми случйно сгенерированными данными.
Если хотите добавить данные в таблицу, то просто

```php
Shop::create([
  'name'          => 'Aliexpress',
  'description'   => 'Chinese store',
  'warranty'      => false,
  'delivery_time' => '36:00:00'
]);
```